# Async DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background on older device

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I was trying to use this piece of code:

```
func simpleEscaping(test: String, complete: @escaping (_ testEscaped: String)->()) {
    complete(test)
}

func testBgAsync() {
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background)
    simpleEscaping(test: "Test") { (testEscaped) in

        backgroundQueue.async {
            sleep(1)
            print("Test escaped value is: \(testEscaped)")
        }
    }
}

testBgAsync()
```

It works as expected on playground:

> "Test escaped value is: Test"

is displayed.

I also tried this code on actual devices:

> - iPhoneX v11.4
> - iPhone5C v10.3.3

Result is a same for the iPhoneX:

> "Test escaped value is: Test"

For the iPhone5C: no result. Tried to put some breakpoints and saw that the code in the `backgroundQueue.async {}` is not ran.

Is it coming for my bad implementation or something is different depending of the device version?

Comment: Try `QoSClass.utility`.  With `.background` there is the possibility that the code will never be dispatched.

Comment: I changed it and it seems to work. Have you an idea why this code could not be dispatched with .background ?

Comment: .background is a very low priority.  It is possible for items at that priority to never execute, particularly on a lower power device like a 5C

Comment: got it :) thank you very much. Feel free to post this as an answer that I can valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the lowest QoS you should use is `.utility`.

`.background` is a very low priority and items at this priority may *never* be dispatched, particularly on a low power device such as an iPhone 5C